# Different documents shown when entering and exiting the UK - could this lead to immigration assuming I've overstayed?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

When flying into the UK I've shown my (non-EU) **passport** to immigration control and got my regular entry stamp. Upon exiting the UK, the airline employee didn't want to see my passport and instead asked for my Czech **residence permit**. I've tried to get them to enter my passport details instead but the airline employee refused and they've assured me it won't cause any problems.

But this got me wondering — couldn't this lead to a situation where my residence permit isn't matched to my passport and the UK immigration authority assumes I've overstayed? Since no exit stamp is provided when leaving the UK, how can I prove I haven't actually overstayed?

Comment: Who issued your residence permit?

Comment: @GayotFow Czech Republic

Comment: Then no, they are not going to get you for overstaying.  Exit controls take account of people leaving on different travel documents because of the situation you've described.  I needed to ask who issued it because I haven't been tracking enlargement members, but CZ has been a full member for a long time.

Comment: I would assume that matching is never actually done, it is just a theoretical possibility. To be double sure, I would keep a photo of the boarding pass on my cell so I have it accessible if ever needed.

Comment: I have been in and out of the UK with a non-EU passport for the past 15 years. I have never had a single UK 'Exit Stamp' on my passport - I have plenty of those from other countries though.

Comment: @GayotFow care to add your comment as an answer? :)

Comment: @machnine Exit checks were only reintroduced from 8 April 2015 and don't involve exit stamps

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 There still aren't any border checks when exiting by air, only by land

Comment: @Coke the reintroduction of border checks includes exit records for departing air passengers based on information provided to the government by the airlines.

Comment: @phoog Which has always been in place

Comment: @Coke No.  The reintroduction of exit checks included new procedures to match exit records to entry records.  Such procedures were not always in place.

Comment: @Coke although according to this your comment may be correct if you define "always" to mean "since 2004," though it's still not entirely clear: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet

Comment: @phoog I meant it's been in place well before the "Exit check introduction"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've traveled to the UK several times in the same fashion (passport on the way in, residency card on the way out), and at no time did the immigration officer assume I've overstayed on my previous trip. So either the UK doesn't keep a tight track on how long people stay or they've simply matched me in the database by name/birthday.

Either way it's fine.